# Render issue on text move in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, render

I'm working on this website where titles move left/right depending on the X-axis position of the mouse cursor. The titles are absolutely positioned within their container and the move happens with css transform, by applying a 'translateX' value through Javascript.

Everything works fine, but on Safari there's an occasional rendering issue, where the rendering of the moving text seems to echo and lag behind, as you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfWS2.png). For some reason this only happens when the text moves from right to left. Stranger even, it seems to only occur at the bottom stem of the downward stroke of the letter K.

If anyone has an idea what could cause this, that would already be a great help.

Here's a link to the website:
http://staging-kaplan.matthiasdeckx.be/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This CSS rule is one problem: .o-row:after, .o-row:before.  Your page is a resource hog, so that's another.

Comment: You'd better provide [mcve] here...

Answer (score 0):

The downward stroke of the letter K is out of the symbol boundary. That causes the rendering bug in Safari.

The options are:

1. Change font. Choose one without overflowing letters.
2. Extend `.o-banner__animate` by setting `padding: 0 .05em`
3. Cut the K's leg with `.o-banner__animate` `overflow: hidden`

I'd prefer #2.